# C#- Add Image and text to Dialog Form that appears on clicking on a submenu of a Toolstripmenuitem

Tags: c#, forms, image, text, dialog

I have created a ToolStripMenuItem called "About". Underneath "About", I have a submenu called "About MatchingGame". Upon clicking on "About MatchingGame", I want it to display a dialog box. In that box, I want to be able to show an image and some text (one field on top of another).

So far, I have this code for the about menu:

```
private void aboutMatchingGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form dlg1 = new Form();
    dlg1.ShowDialog();           
}
```

This gives me the form dialog that I need, though it is still blank. Is there a way to get the dialog box to show up when looking at the design so that I can add a picture box to it? When I click on "About MatchingGame" from the design file, it just lets me change the text and does not open the form dialog to let me put anything in it. How can I get the dialog form to display what I need (an image and a text field)? I have tried added open file dialog to the source code, but I could not get that  to work (and it doesn't solve the problem of the text). Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to create your own `Form` set up how you want it, and then call it from your code like you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create a new `Form` and add it to your project. Give it a name like "MyForm". Then you can change the form in the designer.

Instead of doing `Form dlg1 = new Form();`, do `MyForm dlg1 = new MyForm();`. The rest of your code can be the same.

Comment: Doing just this generates a compiler error: "The type or namespace name 'My Form' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?" I am guessing something needs to be added elsewhere in the program?

Comment: **Yes, create a new Form and add it to your project.**

Comment: So, I assume that "MyForm" was supposed to be replaced with the name of the form created, not the actual code to be typed, since that is what worked after creating the form. I got the text box to work, it just looks tacky since you can highlight it and see the cursor (though I figured out how to make it multiline and read only). It would be a bonus if I could know how to get rid of the highlighting and the cursor, but it works how it is.

Comment: You got it. It sounds like you need a Label, not a TextBox.